# Wordpress HTTP and HTTPS errors

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a https-website which I wanted to try out with another hosting provider, which does not support ssl for its test accounts. 
I have copied all my data and databases from my old web hosting server to the new hoster.
I have replaced all https references in my database and in wordpress. 
I checked the html source code and no https call is done there.

**Problem**: My javascript does not work on the page, the dev console says it renders a 404 error because it "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - https://example.de/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/script.js". Why does it make a https call there ?

Answer (score 0):

1) How did you migrate your website? Sometimes there are options with serialized arrays you can not just search/replace for HTTPS as this may not replace anything. For migrating your WordPress website use the following tool to convert the database (its de-facto standard):

> https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

This will most likely solve your problem and many others, too.

2) Furthermore do a search and replace on the code of your Theme (you said you have already done it)

3) External URLs may be called with HTTPS so make sure its not an external call

4) Check the server configuration of your new hosting provider - maybe the HTTPS is not the problem but there is something different in server configuration